# Log4j2 socket appender inside a docker container throw connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker, log4j2, connection-refused

I have a springboot app running on docker container. In my app there is a log4j.xml file with socket appender.

```
<Socket name="Socket" host="172.17.0.1" port="5100">
    <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" />
</Socket>
```

In my host server (Ubuntu server) its listing port 5100 by logstash. Out put of "netstat -tulpn" command in host is as below.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

But when the springboot server up its getting connection refused error.

```
2021-07-30 05:20:47,646 main ERROR TcpSocketManager (TCP:172.17.0.1:5100) caught exception and will continue: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

I tried with "host.docker.internal" also and its not working. Can anyone let me know what is the problem with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your `netstat` output, Logstash is listening on `127.0.0.1:5100` only. That means it cannot be accessed from within Docker. You have to make it listen on `172.17.0.1:5100` or `0.0.0.0:5100`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there any other way without changing the logstash listen within docker app do a change for this?

Comment: Why are you asking for another way, are there any reasons why you cannot apply my suggestion?

Comment: I'm totally agree with your suggestion and it should work. But I'm trying to do only the changes in docker side. Without touching the other area. If there is no other ways then I have to move on that.

Comment: The problem lies in "the other area", so there's not much you can do at the Docker side. The only thing that might work if you are under Linux is to use [host network mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to check the possibility on logstash listen change since I can't do the network mode change.

Comment: Check the [`host`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html#plugins-inputs-tcp-host) value in your Logstash configuration.

Comment: I think logstash servers are load balanced with haproxy. I don't have good idea on that area.

Comment: As a quick & dirty workaround you could also use `socat` to make the local address accessible from within Docker, e.g. `socat tcp4-listen:55100,fork,bind=172.17.0.1 tcp4-connect:127.0.0.1:5100`. You'd have to configure log4j to use port 55100 in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.